# Convert time and date from one time zone to another in Roku SG

Tags: roku, brightscript, scenegraph

I have a particular date and time. Now, I want to convert the time according to device current time zone.
Basically what I need is an script that, when provided with a time and a timezone can return the time in another time zone. How can I achieve it ?

Comment: According to the docs https://sdkdocs.roku.com/display/sdkdoc/ifDateTime, it looks like there's a utility function to find the offset from UTC. Check out GetTimeZoneOffset().

Answer (score 0):

According to Roku docs https://developer.roku.com/en-gb/docs/references/brightscript/interfaces/ifdatetime.md the roDateTime object uses ifDateTime interface which has a method called toLocalTime().

You can use it to get the local time of the device, this is easier than calculating the time zone offset.

```
datetime = createobject("roDateTime")
datetime.toLocalTime()
```